# IE8 excel download invalidates chart data series references to named ranges

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, named-ranges

To recreate this problem:

1. Create an Excel workbook (.xlsx).  I'm using Excel 2010, but I'm not sure that matters.
2. Create a named range.
3. Create a chart that refers to the named range for its data series values.  The reference should look something like "workbook.xlsx!NamedRangeName".
4. Use IE8 to download this file from a web server.  Open in Excel (without saving first).

When you try to open the file, Excel complains about invalid references, because somehow "workbook.xlsx" has been replaced with "http://someUrl/filename.xlsx" in the reference to the named range.

The problem does not occur if you save the file first instead of opening it.  It does not occur in IE9 or Firefox either.

I suspect this is related to how IE stores downloaded files.

I'm looking for a workaround, since I assume only Microsoft could actually fix it.  I can only control the server side, not the PC, browser configuration, or user behavior.  I can change the excel files to some extent, but I do need the charts to refer to named ranges.

Comment: If you clear your browser cache does IE8 behave as you want? If yes, can you send headers with the Excel file to prevent it caching (or add a random querystring parameter to the browser link to do the same thing)?

Comment: @Tim I mentioned caching of downloaded files, but I really just meant how it downloads them for opening (as opposed to saving).  I did not mean to imply that the file is being cached and then reloaded from cache on subsequent downloads.  I've edited my question to clarify.

Comment: "Works fine if you save the file first instead of opening it." Doesn't this answer your question? I think this would fall within "best practices", even if it doesn't also break in other browsers.

Comment: @Jon, that did not completely answer my question because it is users of the application who are downloading the files, and it is not reasonable for me to tell them they must save the file first.  However, that did point me in the direction of a workaround.  I will add it as an answer.

Comment: @ToddGibson The question is too vague, it looks like you've pasted an assignment right into the question box... please edit your question omitting non relevant information such as dealing with named ranges.

Comment: @Oerd, I phrased the question in the form of steps to reproduce the problem, because I thought that would be the clearest - the problem only occurs in a very specific situation.  The corruption of the named ranges is hardly irrelevant - it IS the problem.  If you have specific suggestions for improving my question, please let me know.

Comment: @ToddGibson: sorry if I seemed to harsh before. I have a better understanding of your question after what you just wrote. I still think that there might be some better way to phrase your question (i.e. explain that steps to reproduce problem follow / use a numbered list for steps / etc) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I found was to add to the download page:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8 ]>
<meta name="DownloadOptions" content="noopen" />
<![endif]-->
```

This removes the option for the user to open the file without saving it first.